# Widget ios14 from flutter

Tags: flutter, swiftui

Can anyone help me to convert the below code to send an array of texts from flutter to swift so can give me a widget list

I am sending all data from flutter to swift using this plugin
https://github.com/fasky-software/flutter_widgetkit

and I follow this tutorial

https://thomas-leiter.medium.com/develop-an-ios-14-widget-in-flutter-with-swiftui-e98eaff2c606

I can have only one text on widget but i want to send a list with 5 titles(texts)

````
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct FlutterData: Decodable, Hashable {
    let text: String
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let flutterData: FlutterData?
}

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
            SimpleEntry(date: Date(), flutterData: FlutterData(text: "Hello from Flutter"))
        }

        func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), flutterData: FlutterData(text: "Hello from Flutter"))
            completion(entry)
        }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
            var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
            
            let sharedDefaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.widgetek")
            var flutterData: FlutterData? = nil
            
            if(sharedDefaults != nil) {
                do {
                  let shared = sharedDefaults?.string(forKey: "widgetData")
                  if(shared != nil){
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    flutterData = try decoder.decode(FlutterData.self, from: shared!.data(using: .utf8)!)
                  }
                } catch {
                  print(error)
                }
            }
        let currentDate = Date()
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 24, to: currentDate)!
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, flutterData: flutterData)
        entries.append(entry)

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct FlutterWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
       
       private var FlutterDataView: some View {
        
         Text(entry.flutterData!.text)
       }
       
       private var NoDataView: some View {
         Text("No Pendind Reminder found! Go to the RemindMe App")
       }
       
       var body: some View {
         if(entry.flutterData == nil) {
           NoDataView
         } else {
           FlutterDataView
         }
       }
}


@main
struct FlutterWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "FlutterWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            FlutterWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Flutter Example Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget which communicates with a Flutter App.")
    }
}

struct FlutterWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FlutterWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), flutterData: nil))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}```
````

Comment: *I want to send a list with 5 titles(texts)* - where is this data? I can see that you retrieve only one string (`let shared = sharedDefaults?.string(forKey: "widgetData")`). Where is the rest?

Comment: I dont know at all swift.... this is the reason that I am asking :)

Comment: I found this on web and I think I am in correct road!?struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    
    var date : Date
    var widgetData : [FlutterData]
}

struct FlutterData: Decodable,Hashable{
    
    var date : CGFloat
    var reminder : String
}